# Как я могу исправить относительный путь в импортах внутри структуры NestJS проекта?

Tags: node.js, nestjs

Я работаю над [проектом](https://github.com/invzbl3/rest-api-nestjs), следуя [статье](https://medium.com/swlh/create-an-api-rest-with-nestjs-1954723e8234). Во время построения структуры, возникли трудности с импортами на шаге по созданию сервиса `UserService`.

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from "@nestjs/typeorm"; 
import { UserDto } from 'src/user/dto/user.dto'; 
import { Repository } from "typeorm"; 
import { UserEntity } from './../../entity/user.entity';

@Injectable()
export class UserService { 

constructor( 
@InjectRepository(UserEntity) private userRepository: Repository<UserEntity> 
}{}
 
create(user: UserDto): Promise<UserDto> {
   return this.userRepository.save(user); 
 }
 findAll(): Promise<UserDto[]> {
   return this.userRepository.find(); 
 } 
}
```

Проблема возникает конкретно на строчках с относительным путём, а именно:

```
import { UserDto } from 'src/user/dto/user.dto';
```

и соответственно:

```
import { UserEntity } from './../../entity/user.entity';
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто-нибудь знает, что может быть причиной этой проблемы? Что я могу исправить со своей стороны?

*UserDTO*:

```
import { IsNumber, IsString } from 'class-validator';
export class UserDto { 
  @IsNumber() id: number;
  @IsString() name: string;
  @IsString() lastName: string; 
}
```

*UserEntity*:

```
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';
  @Entity() 
  export class UserEntity { 

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn() 
  id: number;

  @Column({ nullable: false }) 
  name: string;
 
  @Column({ name: 'last_name', nullable: false }) 
  lastName: string; 
}
```

В проекте данной статьи по такому же принципу проблем нет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но *со своей стороны* я вижу ошибки связанные с импортом проекта.

Также есть следующего плана [структура проекта](https://gist.github.com/invzbl3/34b10748e94ef709d98ca7d67a8a8124#file-project-structure-L1). Нужно ли заменять относительный путь на абсолютной или я что-то упускаю в самом построении?

Я готов предоставить более подробную информацию, если это поможет обнаружить и устранить проблему.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: c такими настройками, как у вас в tsconfig.json и package.json, нужно прописывать относительный путь. `import { UserEntity } from '../../entity/user.entity/user.entity';` и `import { UserDto } from '../../dto/user.dto/user.dto';`

Comment: @nörbörnën, Благодарю! Подсказка с импортами то, что нужно. Как добью вопрос с `UserService` кодом, оставлю полноценный ответ.